# Drag N' Drop in Virtual PC 2007

Tags: windows, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm running Windows 7 with Virtual PC 2007.  I was wondering if there was any way to Drag n' drop files from the hosting computer to the VM, or vica-versa. The VM I'm connecting to is Windows XP.

Comment: Ask this in superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop is enabled by installing Virtual Machine Additions on the VM (in Virtual PC 2007: **Action** menu > **Install or Update Virtual Machine Additions**).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, drag and drop between host and guest should Just Work, as long as the guest has the correct VPC extensions installed. It certainly used to work with WinXP as the host, though I haven't specifically tried it in Win7.