# Getting Drag and Drop to Work in Virtual PC 2007 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drag N' Drop in Virtual PC 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/62131/drag-n-drop-in-virtual-pc-2007)

I have Virtual PC 2007 installed on my Windows 7 machine. Before anyone asks, I have installed VPC 2007 because my machine does not support the new Virtual PC for Windows 7.

Everythings working fine, except for the drag and drop file feature. On my old Windows XP machine the drag and drop feature works fine, but on Windows 7, nothing happens. I just get the "no drop" cursor. I HAVE installed Virtual Machine Additions and have run Virtual PC under XP Compatability, but still nothing.

The Virtual Machines I have tried draging and dropping files onto on are:

Windows 2000
Windows XP
Windows 98

and as I said they all have Virtual Machine Additions on them.

Whats going on? How can I get the drag and drop feature working?

I did see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/62131/virtual-pc-2007-drag-n-drop-question) question, but it still doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer. It won't and it won't be fixed.

Since Virtual PC 2007 is not officially support on Windows 7, and the reason Virtual PC was reworked and re-introduced along with Windows 7, there is no plans from Microsoft to do further support for Windows 7 including the guest additions on Virtual PC 2007. Best bet is to upgrade your Virtual Machine to the new version.

We had this problem during the beta tests and this was the official response from Microsoft when asked during various live meetings.

If you can't use the new Virtual PC look at moving to [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org). It has native support for Virtual PC images and you will only need to install the Virtual Box extensions. However remove the Virtual PC extensions first, and you may have to update some hardware devices. I have used it often to mount and run VHD's directly.

Comment: Oh... Know any way to get new Virtual PC for 7 on a laptop without hardware assisted virtualisation without a major hardware upgrade?

Comment: @Kryten. Nope. It was a big issue when they launched, but the truth is most machines today come with it, and it is the only way to really run it. I have updated my answer with a **working** alternative application that will not require you to convert anything.

Comment: How is VirtualBox's support for Windows Guest Systems? Because when I last tried, it was noted that Windows did not perform very well. Has this changed?

Comment: I've been using VirtualBox since version 2.0 and have never had any issues with Windows Support. I am running complete development boxes with Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 in the current 3.1.2 and have absolutely no issues with performance. The team actively develops on the software and release new version extremely often and fix bugs well. It has been very stable for some time now and highly recommend by many, including me. If I can't use a Hyper-V box I use VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Have found out Microsoft is now offering a update to enable Virtual PC on non-virtualization CPU's...